# Is the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office out of CTP yet?

Tags: microsoft-office

I have been playing with the [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5124) and noticed there was the [Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) available but some links show it as being in CTP.

My question; is it now released as stable?

Comment: It was out of CTP when Office 2013 was released. 11/20/2013 is around the time Office 2013 went RTM.

Comment: @Ramhound Do you have a corroborating link please? If you put your comment as an Answer with a link I can accept it =)

Comment: As you have requested.  I decided to make it more then "here is Microsoft saying its RTW" I missed the fact the download website clear indicates its RTW also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to find evidence to prove that the RTW version was released.

> The download page for the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office is now
>   providing the RTW version of Open XML SDK 2.5. You can use this
>   version for production. We are now updating the documentation in MSDN.
>   Until the publication of the updated documentation, please refer to
>   the SDK document in Productivity Tool.
>
> The differences between the CTP and the RTW versions exist in the
>   classes of "Office15", and those are renamed to "Office2013". Also we
>   are preparing a set of sample code demonstrating how the classes can
>   be used.
>
> Regards,
>
> Kazunori Matsuura Open XML SDK 2.5

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oxmlsdk/threads?announcementId=1aef37e6-9ba7-41d1-8ff9-bed518882e4a#1aef37e6-9ba7-41d1-8ff9-bed518882e4a)

[ECMA-376 Standard, 4th Edition](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oxmlsdk/threads?announcementId=069b4d5e-0bce-49ec-97b9-68399b6e4154#069b4d5e-0bce-49ec-97b9-68399b6e4154)

[Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425)

[image: OpenXML SDK 2.5]